# Headers being sent twice due to callback

Tags: node.js, express

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

var mysqlPool = mysql.createPool({...});

router.post("/", function(req, res, nxt) {
    req.assert('email', 'Valid email required').notEmpty().isEmail();
    var errors = req.validationErrors(true);

    if (errors) {
        mysqlPool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
            if(err) return nxt(err);
            conn.query( 'SELECT * FROM guestbook', function( err, result ) {
                conn.release();
                return res.render("index", {signs: result, errors: errors || {}})
            });
        });
    }

    mysqlPool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
        if(err) return nxt(err);
        conn.query( 'INSERT INTO guestbook ( name, email, message ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ? )',
            [ req.body.name, req.body.email, req.body.message ],
            function( err, result ) {
                conn.release();
                req.flash( 'success_msg', 'Successfully signed guestbook' );
                res.redirect( "/" );
        });
    });
});
```

Hi there, im new to node.js

Here is the problem im facing, if there is validation error, this code will produce `Can't set headers after they are sent`

Im fully aware of why this is happening.
This is because of async callback in the `mysqlPool.getConnection` get registered and then the flow continue straight to the below code right after it

To remedy this, i add `return` statement

```
if (errors) {
    return mysqlPool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {...});
}

return mysqlPool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {...});
```

Yes, it indeed solved my problem.
But i feel something wrong with it.
Is there a better approach to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: You could wrap the 2nd `getConnection()`, with the `INSERT` query, in an `else` block.

Comment: Though, this type of question might be more fitting on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski isnt that library like `promise` or `async` would be better approach?

Comment: Hey @slier , I think something like `promise` or `async` is for different code paths that are dependent on one another.  So a scenario like "I need A and B before I can do C".  In your case, unless there's more code, the scenario is "If there are errors, render the Index, otherwise, show the flash message and redirect".  It looks alright to me, especially if you just wrap the 2nd block in an `else` block as @JonathanLonowski suggested.  I would also suggest pulling the blocks into their own methods.  Cheers, Brennan